# How to condense 3 queries into 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help with these lines of code to basically condense them into 1 query. Im pulling the 3 queries from a database on mySQL. The reason I'm using 3 queries is because I need to do the " echo json_encode() " line. I could literally just do 1 query but then I dont know how I could separate the results out to mapCode,used and active. Any help is appreciated :) thanks!

P.S Im using this code to send to an html ajax pull where I set them as variables on the html script. 
Also. I understand the question is really accurate didnt know what else to call it if you have any suggestions please tell me so i can edit it (if i can).

Code :

```
$query = "SELECT mapCode FROM mapCodes";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$mapCode = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$query1 = "SELECT used FROM mapCodes";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
$used = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);

$query2 = "SELECT active FROM mapCodes";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$active = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);

echo json_encode(array('mapCode'=>$mapCode[0], 'used'=>$used[0], 'active'=>$active[0]));
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query In your case, the desired result is a MySQL result which can then be parsed and Jason encoded in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to take a look at the official documentation, you can do it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). Before ask question you should do a quick research because it's very trivial question.

You want to get 3 columns from one table so just do a simple SELECT, after keyword `SELECT` just include all three column's names separated by comma, in your case it will be

```
SELECT mapCode, used, active FROM mapCodes;
```

Comment: yes i know i can do that its just if i do that then json_encode() i would encode the 3 variables into 1. I dont want to do that hence this question. Thanks tho

Comment: So just ```print_r()``` your result when you use query similar to mine. You will get array containing 3 other arrays. It will be easier to you to work with an array which is known to you. When you use above query and you save your result to ```$result``` variable, instead ```echo json_encode(array('mapCode'=>$mapCode[0], 'used'=>$used[0], 'active'=>$active[0]));``` you will get something like that ```echo json_encode(array('mapCode'=>$result[0], 'used'=>$result[1], 'active'=>$result[2]));```

Comment: thanks you were right I should have researched harder. Thanks :)